# CoreData releation 1-many and 1 to many

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data

I have 3 entities ( User, Album and Photo) with the following attributes. [image]
I cant read data from Photo ( Album 1:<->>many Photo).
This is how i save my data

```
var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var currentUser: User!
    @IBAction func saveButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
            let album = Album(context: managedContext)
            album.albumMainPhoto = photoArray[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) as! NSData
            album.albumDescription = photoDescriptionArray[0]
            album.numberOfPhotos = Int16(photoArray.count)
            let photos = Photo(context: managedContext)
            photos.colorAsHex = "hexTest"
            photos.photo = photoArray[0].jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) as! NSData
            photos.photoDescription = "descTest"
            photos.photoStyle = "styleTest"

            album.addToAlbumToPhotos(photos)
            currentUser?.addToUserToAlbum(album)
            do {
                try managedContext.save()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("save error: \(error), description: \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
```

and i retrieve data by this

```
guard let album = currentUser?.userToAlbum?[indexPath.row] as? Album,
            let albumTitle = album.albumDescription as String?,
            let albumPhotosCount = album.numberOfPhotos as Int16?,
            let albumMainPhoto = album.albumMainPhoto as NSData? else {
                return
        }

        guard let photos = Albums?.albumToPhotos?[indexPath.row] as? Photo,
            let photodesc = photos.photoDescription as String?,
            let photoImage = photos.photo as NSData?
            else {
                return
        }
```

The first option ( guard let album) works perfectly , i cant read albumDescription, numberOfPhotos and see image albumMainPhoto. When i try to use this on photos it can't read data. I am still new to coreData, so i might do something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get data with this :

```
guard let album = currentUser?.userToAlbum?[indexPath.row] as? Album,
            let albumTitle = album.albumDescription as String?,
            let albumPhotosCount = album.numberOfPhotos as Int16?,
            let albumMainPhoto = album.albumMainPhoto as NSData?,
            let photos = album.albumToPhotos?[indexPath.row] as? Photo,
            let photosDes = photos.photoDescription as String?
            else {
                return
        }
```